# windows pc beeps continuously if i give cat [exe] on connected arm board

Tags: android, windows, window, beagleboard

I am connecting android testphone to windows pc via usb cable. I do adb shell in cmd and enter shell on the test phone. If by mistake I give

`cat some-executable`

then the PC starts beeping continuously, even if i disconnect the device the PC keeps on beeping. I had to long press the pc power button, shutdown to make beeping stop. when googled didnt find much info. Can anyone tell me if there is any way to get out of such situatuion

Comment: Have you tried killing the process `adb` using process manager?

Comment: My PC completely hangs at this time. Not able to do Ctrl+c and `adb kill-server` or even open one more promt and give `adb kill-server`

Answer (score 1):

that is normal and kind of a feature. Inside the binary there are beeping characters ( 0x7 BELL (Beep) ) - and this is what you hear.
I think the reading was long done ( bottleneck is the output here ) - so what you hear after disconnect is the buffer. Killing adb should help in this case - try:

```
adb kill-server
```

Comment: My PC completely hangs at this time. Not able to do Ctrl+c and `adb kill-server` or even open one more promt and give `adb kill-server`

Comment: then get a proper OS 
*SCNR*